How to build Svelte into modular Components as ES modules?
I'm working on app that's mostly plain JS. And I need to plug some components made with Svelte.
It doesn't have to be WebComponents, just plain JS (even better TS as ES module) would be good enough. The problem - how to make it modular?
The app has the following structure:
app/
- lib/shared-lib.ts
- table.svelte   // imports lib/shared-lib.ts
- toolbar.svelte // imports lib/shared-lib.ts
- app.ts         // uses plain JS for UI, and also imports lib/shared-lib.ts

How can I built those table.svelte and toolbar.svelte into table.js and toolbar.js? As ES modules?
I don't want svelte compiler to produce the full bundle for each component, with lib/shared-lib.ts. I need only convert svelte to js that would have ES module import statement import 'lib/shared-lib'. So after the svelte build step the folder will be:
app/
- lib/shared-lib.ts
- table.svelte   // imports lib/shared-lib.ts
- table.ts       // <-- compiled by svelte, js also will be fine
- toolbar.svelte // imports lib/shared-lib.ts
- toolbar.js     // <-- compiled by svelte, js also will be fine
- app.ts         // uses plain JS for UI, and also imports lib/shared-lib.ts

And after that I can build the whole app using other build tools, with compiled svelte components being just a plain TS/JS ES module, as any other file in app.


I suppose that you can do this by using the Svelte compiler directly, where the compiler would then output the compilation of the Svelte file.  The compiler does not bundle, so the imports are not a problem.  The tool that bundles is rollup, and if you use the compiler directly, you won't have to worry about the bundle.
However, there's a simpler method:  Use a Sveltekit project.  Create a Sveltekit project and put all you want in your reusable (NPM?) package in the src/lib folder and then run npm run package.  The dist folder will contain what you need, which can be published to npmjs.com by running npm publish.
